# How to direct jQuery's .html method to outer HTML wrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I'm trying to toggle between two chunks of HTML, a `span` and an `anchor`. For example:

```
<span class="current">Demo</span>
```

toggle with:

```
<a href="http://someurl/" class="demo">Demo</a>
```

I've tried the following:

```
$(spanDemo).html('<a href="http://someurl/" class="demo">Demo</a>');
$(anchorDemo).html('<span class="current">Demo</span>');
```

However, the elements get wrapped inside each other, and the DOM result is:

```
<span class="current"><a href="http://someurl/" class="demo">Demo</a></span>
```

and

```
<a href="http://someurl/" class="demo"><span class="current">Demo</span></a>
```

THE QUESTION IS:
How can I use replace the entire wrap, instead of wrapping these HTML chunks together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
$('.current').replaceWith('<a href="http://someurl/" class="demo">Demo</a>');
$('.demo').replaceWith('<span class="current">Demo</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a div with a class instead, and then set it's contents.

Instead of worrying about removing and adding, and since you're using jQuery, you could also hide and show with both "on" the page, simply hidden until needed.

Comment: Thanks. However, See my reply to slandau.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each element in a `div`. When you call `html()` you are replacing the innerHTML of that element.

Change your HTML to something like this:

```
<div id="span">
    <span class="current">Demo</span>
</div>
<div id="a">
    <a href="http://someurl/" class="demo">Demo</a>
</div>
```

And then toggle with these selectors:

```
$('#span').html('<a href="http://someurl/" class="demo">Demo</a>');
$('#a').html('<span class="current">Demo</span>');
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: I have no control over the DOM. This is an interface for a 3rd party.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Then yeah use the answer with the most votes, the replace.